# Conversion to PDF Fails

Tags: pdftex, undefined

While running "pdflatex refman", I see some errors due to one of the text file.

The error that I get on console is: ! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8'.

When I remove the identified text file the PDF is created for the doxygen documentation.

Thank you for your help.

Regards,

Sudheer

Comment: please add a minimum working example that we can compile

Comment: I figured out that in some places of the text they used the following symbol ’ instead of '. When I replace the following ’ with ' the output gets generated. I am not sure whether I can replace the first symbol or not. Any suggestions.